# Reverse Geocoding to get an actual business name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, geocoding

This is more a general question but my particular case involves a ruby/rails app using the Google map APIs (v2).

I'd like to take a lat/long point and get an address (standard rev geocode) and then take that address one step further to see if there is a specific business name associated with it.

So, as an example say (numbers pulled out of nowhere):

41.23232, -81.98938 => 1500 Prospect Avenue, Cleveland Ohio 44134 => Winking Lizard Tavern

Is there a standard way to do that second lookup?

I guess I could programatically construct a URL to the reverse address search on whitepages dot com and then parse the response HTML, but I was hoping there would be a better way.

UPDATE:

Answer updated to include Google information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) whitepages.com has an API that provides this functionality:

http://developer.whitepages.com/docs/Methods/reverse_address

Currently limited to 1500 queries/hour.

2) Google Maps **Enterprise** API also offers this as part of their "Advanced Geocoding" functionality.

Pricing of the enterprise edition starts at 10,000 USD/year.

In my case unfortunately, this exceeds my project's budget by approximately 10,000 USD. :)

Comment: I will donate 1 USD per year to your project.